# JSF 2 (MyFaces 2.0.12): Preventing Login page from being Cached issues

Tags: jsp, jsf, myfaces

To prevent Login screen on my application from being cached by the browser i'm using the following peace of code :

```
public class SessionHandler implements Filter {


public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if ((request instanceof HttpServletRequest) && (response instanceof HttpServletResponse)) {
    .
    .
    .
    try {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        //ignore images/css...etc
        if(!httpReq.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpReq.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)){
            //if login screen or home - don't cache 
            if(httpReq.getRequestURI().equalsIgnoreCase("/jsp/auth_login.faces")
                    || httpReq.getRequestURI().equalsIgnoreCase("/jsp/def_home.faces") ) {


                System.out.println(httpReq.getRequestURI() + " ----- " + " WON'T BE CACHED");

                httpRes.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
                httpRes.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
                httpRes.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.                    
            }
        }           
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    ...
```

Using code I've found in one of the questions answered here by `BalusC` to prevent caching. My problem is that it seems the page is still being cached by the browser. Using Chrome Developer Tools to view HTML header of page i see the following on initial page load:

[image]

and if go back to login page after successful login i see:

[image]

Is anyone able to tell me why the login page is being cached?

Comment: Are seeing the debugging statement (System.out) you added when you request the login page?

Comment: yes the posted code above is executed when loading login page

Comment: What are the response headers of the 1st request? Assuming that your filter does its job properly, then this suggests that you haven't cleared your browser's cache after changing the response headers.

Comment: I looked into header file and noticed the logic isn't getting applied when the application is deployed under path other than root. I made the changes (see answer and seems to be working as expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused due to implicit lookup of request URI where in cases in which the application was not deployed under root path the logic was not being used.

```
    if(!httpReq.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpReq.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)){
        //if login screen or home - don't cache 
        if(httpReq.getRequestURI().equalsIgnoreCase("/jsp/auth_login.faces")
                || httpReq.getRequestURI().equalsIgnoreCase("/jsp/def_home.faces") )
```

was changed to:

```
    if(!httpReq.getRequestURI().startsWith(httpReq.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)){
        //if login screen or home - don't cache 
        if(httpReq.getRequestURI().endsWith("/jsp/auth_login.faces")
                || httpReq.getRequestURI().endsWith("/jsp/def_home.faces") )
```

and it's all working as intended.